# if VPN does not encrypt data between VPN Server and Web Server, then why ISP is not able to throttle streaming in a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, encryption, streaming

I understand VPN does not encrypt communication between VPN Server and Web Server (e.g. Netflix server)
I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vs3QhEx_3w&feature=youtu.be)
In this user claims that using VPN, ISP is not able to throttle streaming of Netflix data packets.

If the communication between VPN Server and Netflix server was not encrypted..why ISP not able to throttle Netflix..

P.S I am networking noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can, but it's a different ISP, which is playing nicer.

The user's ISP, which is throttling, does not know anything about the data that is fetched through the VPN connection. At the other end of the VPN connection, there's a different ISP between the VPN server and Netflix, which does not throttle.